# Toolchain binaries cannot be found

Tags: linux, arm, cross-platform, embedded-linux, gnu-toolchain

Trying to build recent version of u-boot bootloader for my mini2440 ARM board I managed to download a toolchain package from codesourcery and extract it to following path: /usr/local/arm-2008q3/

I also exported following values for current session:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/arm-2008q3/bin
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-
```

When I run make I get a following output and I cant figure out why:

```
make: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: Command not found
for dir in tools examples api_examples ; do make -C $dir _depend ; done
make[1]: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: Command not found
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/deth/uboot/mini2440/tools'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `_depend'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/deth/uboot/mini2440/tools'
make[1]: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: Command not found
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/deth/uboot/mini2440/examples'
/bin/sh: 1: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: not found
```

I double checked everything and binaries indeed reside in mentioned folder but... Please explain where I'm wrong.

Comment: All the binaries do in fact have execute permission.

Comment: You are trying to run 6 years old binaries on a modern operating system. Could it be libc incompatibilities? What output do you get from `ldd /usr/local/arm-2008q3/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc`?

Comment: unixsmurf, in general you're right, it's always better to use recent version. I was just too lazy at that moment to perform all the registration process to get the latest one. However, after the solution was found the old binaries worked as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after almost three days of headbanging into the wall I managed to solve this. To be honest I might have never solved it if occasionally hadn't installed the COdesourcery toolchain with executable installer which they also provide. After doing that the manually unpacked version started to execute! This of course led to a conclusion that there were libraries missing. I tried to reproduce the problem on separate virtual machine and voila, here are couple of words that solved the whole issue:

sudo apt-get install **lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0**

Hope this will help someone, and thanks to everyone for help!